# Which Remote Desktop works with Control Keys?

Tags: ios, keyboard, remote-desktop

I am trying to control an iTerm2 session on an iPad mini through Remote Desktop using an Apple BT keyboard (Japanese).

When I tried this out with Splashtop, the backspace key and all control keys don't work.

Which Remote Desktop works well with the Apple BT keyboard on iPad mini?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [RealVNC VNC Viewer](http://www.realvnc.com/products/ios/).

It allows the capability to use all the keys on a real keyboard (command, control, option, etc.), even the function keys. Almost any `remote deskop` application out there uses VNC to handle the screen sharing. VNC Viewer works just fine with Apple Remote Desktop and Bonjour, Terminal, Xterm, and iTerm2 — just open port 5900.

*There's a free version, and a full version (normally $10 for iOS), although the full version is free at this very moment, so [grab it](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vnc-viewer/id352019548?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo=4) while you can.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure we are talking abut the right thing. You are connecting to Screen Sharing on a Mac from an iPad and the iPad is using an Apple BlueTooth keyboard as an external keyboard.

You want to be able to use the control keys, backspace key and such on the BlueTooth keyboard.

The first and cheapest VNC app to do this is the free "VNC Viewer". The paid version of "Mocha VNC" also works fine.  If you want something that will do the same sort of tunneling as Splashtop then "Screens" works and tunnels via "Screens Connect".

I don't have iTerm on my Mac but everything worked fine in "Terminal".